# iwatch complication not listed under watchface complication list but present in complications section on iphone

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I have created app with complications for iphone and iwatch. while checking for installed complication app is listed under the available complication section on phone but when I try to add complication on the watch its not listed under the complications. please help.

And this occurs in case of iwatch 3 but working fine on iwatch 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the general tab for your Watchkit Extenstion and go to the "Complications Configuration" section and make sure that you have the right complication families checked. There are different families that are supported on series 4 vs series 3. Such as "modular small/large" (series 3) vs "graphic circular/rectangular" series 4.

Also make sure in your "Complication Controller" you have the correct cases set up for each supported complication family.

[image]